# Changing WordPress theme manually

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Hi I was wondering how you would change the wordpress theme manually? Is the configuration that selects the theme in a file or a database?

I tried searching for the table where this is located which stated it would be in the "wp-options" table as either style or template however these were for Wordpress 2.*, I didn't find anything conclusive for 3.6. However upon looking at this table where was no option that would match for a theme. When I changed the theme using WP Admin and did not notice the addition of any new options.

I was wondering if their have been any changes to where the setting that indicates what the activated theme is.

Thanks

*Note: I asked a similar question before but was not very specific in my question.*

Comment: Please post some code examples of what have you tried already.

Comment: Im having trouble finding where it would be in the database. I tried looking in the wp_options table with PHPmyadmin but I could not find anything that would match the theme setting.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, its the combination of two options, take a look on this query result:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name IN('template', 'stylesheet');
```

Of course you can simply change its option_value field and Wordpress will look for the matching folder and stylesheet, otherwise it will give you an awful blank screen.